# getting data from nested json with javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I'm new to coding and have trouble with this nested JSON file.

I want to display the EV-charging stations in Switzerland on a webpage built with HTML, CSS, and JavaScript. For the data, I have an external JSON file that I want to access with JavaScript.

This is the external JSON file "ladestationen_schweiz.json" and I want to access the Google GeoCoordinates "46.68459 7.86187" with JavaScript.

```
{
   "EVSEDataRecord":[
      {
         "Address":{
            "City":"Interlaken",
            "Country":"CHE",
            "HouseNum":"16",
            "PostalCode":"3800",
            "Street":"Alpenstrasse",
            "Floor":null,
            "Region":null,
            "Timezone":null
         },
         "IsOpen24Hours":false,
         "ChargingStationId":"CH*BVS*E001*0001",
         "GeoCoordinates":{
            "Google":"46.68459 7.86187"
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

Could somebody help me?

[Here is a picture of the overview of my project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/27F24.jpg)

Comment: Do you want to fetch JSON file or want to access `GeoCoordinates` property from already accessed json file?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the json you are getting is an array **EVSEDataRecord** so you need to map this to get the single object and then any field inside object you can access.

Below in code i did the same thing
or click [here for demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-byggtj?file=src%2FApp.js)

```
import React from 'react';
import MyData from './ladestationen_schweiz.json';
export default function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>JSON!</h1>
      {MyData.EVSEDataRecord.map((item) => {
        return <div>Google: {item.GeoCoordinates.Google}</div>;
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [Square brackets property accessor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors), [Dot property accessor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors) and [Object/Array destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

```js
const jsonData = {
  "EVSEDataRecord": [{
    "Address": {
      "City": "Interlaken",
      "Country": "CHE",
      "HouseNum": "16",
      "PostalCode": "3800",
      "Street": "Alpenstrasse",
      "Floor": null,
      "Region": null,
      "Timezone": null
    },
    "IsOpen24Hours": !1,
    "ChargingStationId": "CH*BVS*E001*0001",
    "GeoCoordinates": {
      "Google": "46.68459 7.86187"
    }
  }]
}

// Using Square brackets property accessor
console.log(jsonData['EVSEDataRecord'][0]['GeoCoordinates']['Google']);

// Using Dot property accessor
console.log(jsonData.EVSEDataRecord[0].GeoCoordinates.Google);

// using Object destructuring
const {
  EVSEDataRecord: [{
    GeoCoordinates: {
      Google
    }
  }]
} = jsonData;
console.log(Google);
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are not using a preprocessor like Babel, you will need to fetch the json using [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) api because the current ES implementation does not support widely direct json imports.

An example of import using fetch:

```js
fetch("./path/to/your/data.json")
  .then((r) => r.json())
  .then((obj) => console.log(obj));
```

Variable obj will then hold contents of your json file.